# Hudde's cubic proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-history, roots-of-cubics

I've been following the proof of Hudde's description of Cardano's method of cubic roots shown here [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula). Does anyone know where this proof comes from? I can't find a good reference for it eg an article or book.

Comment: There are historical references into Wiki's page. For Cardano's original method, see [Artis Magnae, Sive de Regulis Algebraicis (1545)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Magna_(Cardano_book)).  [Hudde's rule](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Hudde/) appeared first in van Schooten's Exercitatione mathematicae (1657).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find them that helpful but hopefully they'll be okay in conjunction

Comment: Of Cardano's *Artis* there is a [modern translation](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Rules_of_Algebra/ZMZY79bvOPgC?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=cardano+ars+magna+dover&printsec=frontcover).